# Why "being" is incorrect in the sentence below

Tags: differences

- When Charles Lindbergh was attempting his solo transatlantic flight, being very reluctant to have any extra weight on his plane, he refused to carry even a pound of mail, despite being offered $1,000 to do so.
- Very reluctant to have any extra weight on his plane when he attempted his solo transatlantic flight, Charles Lindbergh refused to carry even a pound of mail, despite being offered $1,000 to do so.

Which one is better? First sentence is my answer, the second one is the correct answer, why "being" cannot be used. 
I felt second sentence is too redundant: after reading the sentence until the first comma, then the subject, Charles Lindbergh, appears in the sentence. Is it correct. Anyone could explain those type of question to me?

Thanks for your help, really appreciate it.

Comment: In either version, the sequence does not follow natural logic. *being reluctant* could as well have gone to the end of the sentence, for one.

Comment: Both sentences are too long and unwieldy but I can't see anything grammatically incorrect about the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences more or less say the same thing and are understandable. I don't see any particular issue with "being", although, on close inspection, if you are being very pedantic, you can see some shortcomings in the sentence, which are perhaps why it was marked as "incorrect" (?).

Your sentence *technically* has CL refusing the extra weight *while* he is already undertaking the flight ("When he was attempting [...] he refused [...]").

One might also change "being offered" to "having been offered", simply because the offer surely came before he started the flight as well as before he refused.

But the other sentence is not perfect either. It takes a while to get to the subject, which makes it awkward. Both sentences are unwieldy and could be broken up.

eg,

> Charles Lindbergh attempted his first solo transatlantic flight in
>   1927. Being very reluctant to have any extra weight on his plane, he refused to carry even a pound of mail, despite having been
>   offered $1,000 to do so.